# Solving quaternary quadratic forms modulo $q$ efficiently

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, computational-number-theory

Given a quaternary quadratic equation of form $$Q(a,b,c,d)=m$$ in $\Bbb Z[a,b,c,d]$ with coefficient sizes and $|m|$ bounded in magnitude by $B\in\Bbb N$ where $m\neq0$ if we are looking for solutions modulo $q$ where $q$ is either a prime power or a composite then can the complexity with which we can solve this be $O(\log^\alpha (Bq))$ time at a fixed $\alpha>0$?

Answer (score 2):

See the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0281. I have just implemented this a month ago, and would be happy to share the code.

Comment: I am not looking for evaluation to $0$.

Comment: also can you explain 'efficiently done by randomization'?

Comment: So what do you mean by solving?

Comment: finding a,b,c,d.